# Calling a Clojure function with named parameters from a hash map

Tags: clojure

I would like to be able to pass named parameters to a function from a hash map. Let's say I have a function like this:

```
(defn foo [a & {:keys [b]}] (println a b))
```

I want to be able to call it with parameters coming from a map. I know I can do it like this:

```
(apply foo 1 (mapcat identity {:b 2}))
```

But surely there must be a more idiomatic and less clunky way to do this, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't. But you may use `concat` directly instead of doing it through `mapcat`:

```
(apply foo 1 (apply concat {:b 2}))
```

You may also use `->>` macro to make it clearer (though not shorter):

```
(->> {:b 2}
     (apply concat)
     (apply foo 1))
```

Comment: I like applying `concat`, thanks. Using the threading operator actually makes it less clear, at least to me. :)

Answer (score 1):

Nope, there is no other less clunky way. It would be better to make your `foo` to take a hash-map as parameter and pattern match on it for keys:

```
(defn foo [a {:keys [b]}] (println a b))
(foo 1 {:b 2})
```

Comment: `(foo 1 :b 2)` feels much more idiomatic than `(foo 1 {:b 2})`, at least from the Clojure code I've read.